# How can I make Atifactory docker registry images use docker manifest version 2?

Tags: docker, manifest, artifactory, docker-registry

I'm using JFrog's Artifactory (v4.16.0) as a docker registry and I've noticed that whenever I uploade an image the manifest file is version 1:

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "devops/testimage",
   "tag": "0.0.1",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   [...]
```

The docker image I'm buildling from is version 1.12.3. Is there something I need to do to ensure the manifest is version 2?

Comment: How did you look in the manifest? Downloaded it? Using the UI? If using REST, what was the request url?

Comment: One option that comes to mind is, if you used the Docker Registry API to get the manifest (i.e. `GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>`) then you have to send the `Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` header, otherwise Artifactory assumes the client does not support schema v2 and converts it to v1.

Comment: @yinon - I'm viewing the manifest via the Artifactory webgui where I can inspect it directly. It's version 1 there.

Comment: I assume you are using docker client to push the image to Artifactory, if not please specify how. Also, which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: @yinon Version 4.16.0, I'm just doing a regular docker build and push from the command line.

Comment: Then, according to the info you provided, it should work, I don't see any reason why it doesn't...
You can either put a proxy between your docker daemon and Artifactory - to ensure the manifest is uploaded as schema v2 (trying to narrow down the root cause), or contact JFrog Support - they can help you get to the bottom of it.